# "null" at the end of string from file.readStringUntil()

Tags: arduino, esp32

Im working with esp32s3 feather right now. I need to log some data when there is no WiFi connection. Write works fine for me but when I want to read line with readStringUntil(), i always get "null" at the end of read string. Here is code:

In loop:

```
if ((millis() - sdLast) > sdTime)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < maxSensors; i++)
  {
    if (activeSensors[i] != "")
    {
      String requestData = "{\"data\":[{\"name\":\"" + sensorNames[i] + "\" ,\"temp\": \"" + actTemp[i] + "\",\"hum\": \"" + actHum[i] + "\",\"time\": \"" + actTime[i] + "\",\"scanCount\": \"" + scanCount[i] + "\"}]}\n";
      appendFile(SD, "/all.txt", requestData.c_str());
      sdReady = true;
    }
  }
  sdLast = millis();
}
```

Function to read from file:

```
void readLinesSD(fs::FS &fs, const char *path)
{
  File file = fs.open(path);
  WiFiClient client;
  HTTPClient http;
  http.begin(client, serverName);
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  if (!file)
  {
    Serial.println("Failed to open file for reading");

    return;
  }
  while (file.available())
  {
    buffer = file.readStringUntil('\n');
    serializeJson(doc, buffer);
    Serial.println(buffer);
    int httpResponseCode = http.POST(buffer);
    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
    doc.clear();
    delay(200);
  }
  http.end();
  file.close();
}
```

Append function:

```
void appendFile(fs::FS &fs, const char *path, const char *message)
{
  Serial.printf("Appending to file: %s\n", path);

  File file = fs.open(path, FILE_APPEND);
  if (!file)
  {
    Serial.println("Failed to open file for appending");
    return;
  }
  if (file.print(message))
  {
    Serial.println("Message appended");
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Append failed");
  }
  file.close();
}
```

SO basically I want to save data to file and then, when the WiFi connection is back I want to send data to database for further presentation. When I read file i got this results:

{"data":[{"name":"P RHT 902631" ,"temp": "19.53","hum": "48","time": "1674746950","scanCount": "4"}]}null

{"data":[{"name":"P RHT 90262A" ,"temp": "19.38","hum": "50","time": "1674746957","scanCount": "4"}]}null

{"data":[{"name":"P RHT 902629" ,"temp": "19.36","hum": "49","time": "1674746958","scanCount": "5"}]}null

I tried using some special characters like "%" at the end of lines and then read line untill this special character but got same problem. When I used the same function on my other esp32 board everything was read fine. Anyone know what might cause this problem? Thanks for any help

Comment: What's the code for function `appendFile()` in `appendFile(SD, "/all.txt", requestData.c_str());`?

Comment: Yea, sorry for that :P Added to post

Comment: Sorry, no idea.

Answer (score 0):

I messed up with function to read file. I serialized for no reason. Without it, "null" disapear :)